# Guice API with separate implementations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, architecture, guice

I have been trying to design a software architecture with guice that allows for separate implementations by different teams in different regions.

The idea is like:

```
API-A ->
API-B -> API-Global
API-C ->
```

API Global has a bunch of classes (related to GraphQL) that should be non-interface shells of what needs to be implemented.

Because the region specific APIs depend on the Global package I can't have region specific code there.  Is there a way to create guice bindings in an overall graph that the Global API can find through introspection for consumption?

I looked at Guice multibinds to do this but I am not sure that the best way to do it.  I know this is possible using Spring but would really want to use Guice to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way OSGi and other frameworks handle this is to let each implementation come with a standardized file which contains meta-information (meaning the implementation class), and which Global-API can then find on the classpath to configure itself.

(Consider using a standardized framework instead of reinventing the wheel, but this is the general process which I have seen in these frameworks).